# Should I consider a job offer just based on salary

Tags: salary, new-job, job-change

Zillow has an option of make me move. Its where a person is content with their current house, but would move for enough money.

I was out with a friend and got a job offer in programming. Its a significant increase in salary, 50 percent more. After the interviews, it's seems like I will be in a lower job role than I am currently.

I have a wife and a kid, and my question is basically, all thing being equal, would you consider a job based just on salary, and would it not be almost a disservice to your family to turn down a 50 percent raise.

Comment: If all else is equal, of course takes the money... but you're hinting that all else isn't equal or you wouldn't be hesitating. You need to decide your own priorities and how much weight to give each of them.

Comment: Is it a "real" demotion or just a drop in status?  If it's a "status" thing, you can usually get that back just with good work and reliable results.  If it's a true drop in level (from team lead to line developer, for instance), then I'd worry.

Comment: Of course you should _consider_ the job. 50% is an extremely significant difference. But only you can judge whether the trade-offs are worth it, to you, in your situation.

Comment: Confused as to how this question was voted to close by being opinion-based by the people above, but still gave their opinion to help the OP make a decision to his question. If his question is opinion-based, why comment with a opinionated answer

Comment: @WesleyLong more pay for less responsibility can be looked at as a positive thing as well, I can see your point though

Comment: I mostly agree it is opinion based, but stack overflow has some of the smartest people. Why not get a lot of good, different opinions. Sorry for using the site incorrectly, but the ends justify the means in my `opinion`

Answer (score 3):

Jobs can come and go, so all else being relatively equal, take the money for several reasons in addition to the cash. One of the most telling ones from my viewpoint is that if and when you apply for another job and they ask you how much you make, you give them a higher figure. So they know you're worth a good sum.

Secondly and the clincher in my opinion is that you have a family to support and this will raise their quality of life. And at the end of the day you work because you get paid to. And a family man is always willing to sacrifice a bit of personal security in the interests of his people.

Answer (score 2):

How much would it take to get you to hunt down and murder everyone you care about and then commit suicide?  If your answer is "I wouldn't take that contract", then no, there are other things to consider than just salary.

Your conditions for taking a job will be individual, we can't tell you what tradeoffs to make.  Common considerations are salary, benefits, commute, social utility, enjoyment, hours, growth, future salary, responsibility, company culture.